# relationship between option vol and option payoff

Tags: options, volatility, distribution

Has anyone thought of the relationship between the option vol and distribution of option payoff? for example, I have 1000 paths of simulated underlying prices, keeping all inputs the same but only change vol, I will get 2 sets of option payoffs, each set has 1000 payoffs, let's call then c1 and c2 which correspond to vol1 and vol2. Now we draw a histogram of c1 and c2, which one has a fatter tail? the empirical results suggest that the distribution that corresponds to lower vol has a fatter tail on the right. (it is a put option).
In addition, if it is a call option, will there be an inverse relationship? a.k.a higher vol has a fatter tail.

Comment: If you are telling me that a put option on a low vol stock has *more* big payoffs (in 1000 trials) than a put option on a high vol stock, I think that is not right.